# Reanimate Bootstrap's Progress bar onclick

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Basically I want to animate Bootstrap's progress bar by setting the width from 0 to 100%. The only problem is it only works on the first try. I want it to show the animation once again after clicking the same element.

HTML

```
<div class='progress progress-striped active'>
    <div class='progress-bar progress-bar-success'></div>
</div>

<button class='play'>Animate from 0 to 100%</button>
```

JS

```
$('.play').on('click', function(){
    $(".progress-bar").animate({
    width: "100%"
}, 500);

})
```

CSS

```
.progress {height:18px}
.progress-bar {width:0}
.progress-bar {background-color: #5fb1e2}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9abm0hhy/589/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** I found this jquery plugin that does what exactly I need. http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Easy-jQuery-Progress-Bar-Timer-Plugin-For-Bootstrap-3-progressTimer/

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
var p ;
$('.play').on('click', function(){
if ( p ) {
    p.prependTo( "body" );
    p = null;
  } 
  $(".progress-bar").css('width', 0);
  $(".progress-bar").stop().animate({
    width: "100%"
     }, 500, function() {
       setTimeout(function() {
          p = $(".progress").detach();
          console.log(p);
       }, 1000)

     });
  });
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/9abm0hhy/594/)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Everything is working perfect except when the button is clicked before the progress bar reach 100 it disappears and stops working.

Comment: Updated answer  please check if you feel happy for my answer accept and upvote it.